# How to exclude records that contain a certain part of a string in MongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to exclude some records in a MongoDB query.  I need to exclude records that contain a certain part of a string.

This is what I have so far.  Finding records by date, and excluding records where `user_id` is nil is working.  However, removing records that contain the string is not working.

```
db.collection('' + site_id + '_' + process_name).find({user_id: { $ne: null }, page: { $ne: {$regex:".*.this_string_value.com.*"}}, created_at: {"$gte": new Date("" + date + "")}}).toArray(function(err, result) { ...
```

I'm struggling to find the syntax for this, most examples are about finding a value based on a string, not excluding it so I am having a hard time getting the syntax correct.

If someone out there sees what I am doing wrong and can offer some help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit this question with sample docs, input value & required o/p..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for, those input values are just parts of a string so I can access different tables, it would look something like this `5205a237f4d6985a32000072_table_name` and nothing is required.  That is the query as I have it written now and all the stuff after is just handling the promise that gets returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) as you want to get the pages that doesn't match your regex:

```
page: { $not: /.*somestring.*/}
```

For case insentive:

```
page: { $not: /.*somestring.*/i}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I misunderstood, I thought `$ne` was doing that but I see now it wasn't.  Such an obvious answer, thanks again for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the part of `$not` in the documentation here:
[$not with regular expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not)